# OptaPlanner:Can I use custom changeMove with two variables?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I have two variables: period and room.

Some of them have constraints with special lecture. Some change move is not allowed ,so I want a custom changeMove.

I have checked the examples. But the curriculumcourse doesn't have such situation.

Should I write two changemove class? periodChangeMove and roomChangeMove?

Can anyone tell me how to write it?

sorry , my english is not good.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If you just write `<changeMoveSelector>` it will just unfold into 2 change move selectors (one for each planning variable) and do a `<unionMoveSelector>` over them. In some cases you want a `<cartesianProductMoveSeletor>`, in which case you'll need to configure it explicitly (see docs chapter on move selection).

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I'm sorry.
What I want is changeMove not changeMoveSelector, because I want to filter some combinations for special entity and values.
I have seen the docs and examples but they all have one variable in a custom move. If I have two variables , should I write two changeMove class? periodChangeMove and roomChangeMove?
Am I right to write a custom move?

Comment: In case anyone else stumbled over this:


    <cartesianProductMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <valueSelector variableName="period"/>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <valueSelector variableName="room"/>
      </changeMoveSelector>
    </cartesianProductMoveSelector>

https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#scalingMultiplePlanningVariablesInConstructionHeuristics